# Tangent vectors on the algebra of trigonometric polynomials

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, harmonic-analysis

Let $G$ be a compact real Lie group and ${\sf Trig}(G)$ the algebra of trigonometric polynomials on $G$ (defined in the [Hewitt-Ross, Abstract harmonic analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540048324), (27.7)), i.e. the algebra of functions $u:G\to {\mathbb C}$ which can be represented as complex linear combinations of functions of the form
$$
x\in G\mapsto \langle U(x)\xi,\eta\rangle\in{\mathbb C},
$$
where $U:G\to B(H)$ is an arbitrary irreducible unitary continuous representation of $G$ (in an arbitrary Hilbert space $H$), and $\xi,\eta\in H$.

Let us call a *tangent vector* on ${\sf Trig}(G)$ in a point $a\in G$ an arbitrary linear functional $f:{\sf Trig}(G)\to{\mathbb C}$ such that:

1) $f$ preserves involution:
$$
f(\overline{u})=\overline{f(u)},\qquad u\in {\sf Trig}(G),
$$

2) $f$ satisfies the Leibniz identity in the point $a$:
$$
f(u\cdot v)=u(a)\cdot f(v)+f(u)\cdot v(a), \qquad u,v\in {\sf Trig}(G).
$$

A question: **is it true that every such functional $f:{\sf Trig}(G)\to{\mathbb C}$ is a "true tangent vector" on $G$, i.e. it
can be represented in the form 
$$
f(u)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{u(\gamma(t))-u(\gamma(0))}{t},\qquad u\in {\sf Trig}(G),
$$
for some smooth curve $\gamma:{\mathbb R}\to G$ with $\gamma(0)=a$?**

An equivalent statement: **is it true that every such functional $f:{\sf Trig}(G)\to{\mathbb C}$ can be extended to a functional $h:C^\infty(G)\to{\mathbb C}$ with the same properties?**

Comment: Can you give the definition of $Trig(G)$?

Comment: Mariano, I have made the corrections, now ${\sf Trig}(G)$ is defined.

Comment: Usually one calls this the algebra of matrix coefficients (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_coefficient), yes?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Yes, I do not see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. The functions you have are representation functions on $G$ (the representations are finite dimensional as well); they are thus algebraic functions on the complexification of $G$. It is well known that the "algebraic Lie algebra is the true tangent space for algebraic groups.

Comment: Aakumadula, could you give a reference, please?

Comment: A reference for algebraic lie algebra being same as "holomorphic Lie algebra"? I cannot recall one to mind, but it is easier to give a proof. The algebraic ones give local co-ordinates; so algebraic lie algebra is $n$ dimensional, ($n=dim(G)$). Hence it has the same dimension as the "holomorphic" Lie algebra.

Comment: Yes, this is simple... However you should have some experience in algebraic groups to feel free in this field. Can you recommend a textbook for reading and references?

Comment: I read Chevalley's book on Lie groups (see the chapter on Tannaka duality) and Humphrey's book on linear algebraic groups. Perhaps that will help?

Comment: For me it is not obvious that ${\sf Trig}(G)$ coincides with the algebra of pokynomials on the complexification of $G$. Why is this so?

Comment: This is called Tanaka duality (see Chevalley's book). This is a definition of the complexification. The theorem is that the algebra of (what you refer to as) triginometric functions is finitely generated, for a compact Lie group.

Answer (score 1):

There is some difficulty.
Added in edit: Only if $G$ is not compact, and infinite dimensional $H$ are also used.

1. $G\ni x\mapsto u(x)=\langle U(x)\xi,\eta\rangle$ is in $C^\infty(G)$ if and only if one of $\xi,\eta\in H$ is a smooth vector. See section 5 of [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/moment.pdf) for a complete and transparent proof.
2. If you consider only smooth trigonometric functions, then this is true, since smooth trigonometric functions are dense in $C^\infty(G)$, and the usual proof on manifolds goes through if you replace bump functions by smooth trigonometric functions which approximate bump functions. 
   The Taylor expansion to first order with remainder should go through in the algebra of smooth trigonometric functions.

Is this enough information, or should I try to write down a proof?

Comment: Peter, I am not sure I understood. Are you saying that the problem appears only for non-compact $G$, or for all $G$?

Comment: Only if there are infinte dimensional irreducible unitary representations, so only for noncompact $G$. I did not notice that only had compact $G$ when I wrote my answer.